# LR(1) parsing table with epsilon productions

Tags: parsing, compiler-theory, lr1

I'm having trouble building the collection of sets of items for LR(1) parsers with a grammar containing epsilon productions. For example, given the following grammar (where eps stands for epsilon)

```
S -> a S U
U -> b
  |  eps
```

State0 would be

```
S' -> .S, $
S -> .a S U, $
```

Moving with 'a' from State0 would give the following state, let's call it State2

```
S -> a .S U, $
S -> .a S U, $/???
```

In order to have the lookahead for the second item of State2 I need to calculate FIRST(U$). I know that FIRST(U) = {'b', eps}. My first question is: the lookaheads of the second item of State2 are $ and 'b'? Since U can be eps, my brain tells me that I can have $ as a lookahead as well, not just 'b'. It would have been just 'b' if FIRST(U) would have been just {'b'}. Is that correct?

Second question: at some point I will have a state as the following one

```
S -> a S .U, $
U -> .b, $
U -> .eps, $
```

What do I do here? Do I need to move with eps and have a set with the item `U -> eps., $`? What if I have another terminal as lookahead, i.e. `X -> .eps, a/$`? And if I move, ending up having a set of the form `X -> eps., $`, do I reduce?

And more: do I need to insert eps in the parse table as a symbol?

Thanks

Comment: What are you using as a textbook? It surprises me that there are no examples with nullable non-terminals.

Comment: The Dragon Book. I don't really know if I missed some parts, but I didn't read about how to handle these kind of situations specifically...

Comment: Yup. I dug out my copy of the Dragon Book and indeed there is no worked example of an LR automaton with an ε-production. Still, the book is clear that ε represents the empty sequence of symbols, not a special symbol. (Indeed, the book always uses Greek letters for sequences of symbols and Roman letters for individual symbols, which has become a standard convention.)...

Comment: Also, its definition of FIRST(α) is, in effect, "the set of possible first characters in a derivation of α plus ε if α could derive the empty set, which means that it is a subset of `Σ ∪ ε`. But in the case of FIRST(β$) it is clear that Β$ cannot derive the empty sequence, so the FIRST set must be a subset of Σ.

Answer (score 7):

1. `FIRST(U$)` means "the set of symbols which could be first in a derivation of `U$`". Clearly, if `U` can derive the empty string, `$` must be part of this set. The end-of-input marker `$` ensures that we never have to worry about epsilons in the `FIRST` sets. (If we were doing LR(k) instead of LR(1), we would use `k` end markers so that all the strings in `FIRSTk` had length `k`.
2. The item associated with `U →`  (or with `U → ε` if you insist) is `U → •` . In other words, it is reducible and should trigger a reduce action on matching lookahead.
3. `ε` is not a symbol; we only use it (sometimes) to make the empty string visible. But the empty string is empty.