# LR parser for epsilon

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, dfa, lr-grammar

I've recently implemented an LR(1) parser (without epsilon), and have been wondering how I would implement epsilon in the parsing algorithm (note: not the table construction algorithm). This is my grammar:

```
start -> A b
b -> B | \epsilon
```

I've followed the steps listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50396287/11059315) and got this as a result from my parser (table):

```
state 0 on symbol start: 1
state 0 on symbol A: shift and goto state 2
state 1 on symbol $: accept
state 2 on symbol b: 3
state 2 on symbol B: shift and goto state 4
state 2 on symbol $: reduce b → 
state 3 on symbol $: reduce start → A b
state 4 on symbol $: reduce b → B
```

The table listed above is correct, but when I try to parse `A`, there is no transition:

```
error: no transition in table for (0, 'b')
```

This is how my stack looks:

```
[0]
[0, 'A', 2]
[0, 'b'] # stack during the error
```

Now, I notice that there is not a state on the top, which is a problem, but I have no clue what to add after it. My paring code is based upon the one over [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/compiler_design/compiler_design_bottom_up_parser.htm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That stack is definitely wrong, and it seems likely that it is leading to the error (although hard to say without seeing the code).

Here's what you would expect:

```
            LOOK
STACK       AHEAD   ACTION
[0]         A       shift, goto state 2    pushes A (shift) and new state (2)
[0 A 2]     $       reduce b ->            pops 0 pairs, pushes b (reduce) 
[0 A 2 b]           + goto 3               action for b in state 2
[0 A 2 b 3] $       reduce start -> A b    pops 2 pairs, pushes start (reduce)
[0 start]           + goto 1               action for start in state 0
[0 start 1] $       accept
```

If I had to wager a guess, I'd say that you are popping one symbol for an ε right-hand side. As I've mentioned elsewhere (including the answer you cite), *ε is nothing*. It is zero symbols and popping it pops nothing.

Comment: Ah, ok. I forgot not to pop epsilon. Thanks!

Comment: One last question-- I was reading a few posts about LR(1) and epsilon, and FOLLOW sets were mentioned. What do FOLLOW sets have to do with this?

Comment: As with the pretty PDA diagrams, bison has a nice trace facility which will tell you exactly what the parser is doing at each step, including stack printouts.

Comment: FOLLOW sets are not used in CLR, so nothing.

Comment: Most likely got mixed up :-)

Comment: They're used to compute SLR items, though. Maybe that's what the posts were about. Would have to see the posts.